# Updating dictionaries using files

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following file, and I need to update two dictionaries. One of these maps a persons friends and the other maps a persons networks. The file is in the following format:
    Pritchett, Jay
    Pritchett, Gloria
    Delgado, Manny
    Dunphy, Claire

```
Dunphy, Claire
Parent Teacher Association
Dunphy, Phil
Pritchett, Mitchell
Pritchett, Jay

Scrooge, McDuck

Delgado, Manny
Chess Club
Pritchett, Gloria
Pritchett, Jay
Dunphy, Luke

Pritchett, Mitchell
Law Association
Dunphy, Claire
Tucker, Cameron
Dunphy, Luke

Dunphy, Alex
Orchestra
Chess Club
Dunphy, Luke

Tucker, Cameron
Clown School
Wizard of Oz Fan Club
Pritchett, Mitchell
Pritchett, Gloria

Dunphy, Haley Gwendolyn
D-Money, Dylan
D-Cat, Gilbert

Dunphy, Phil
Real Estate Association
Dunphy, Claire
Dunphy, Luke

D-Money, Dylan
D-Cat, Chairman

Dunphy, Haley Gwendolyn

Pritchett, Gloria
Parent Teacher Association
Pritchett, Jay 
Tucker, Cameron
Delgado, Manny

Dunphy, Luke
Delgado, Manny
Dunphy, Alex
Dunphy, Phil
Pritchett, Mitchell
```

I am using the readline() approach to read the file and update the dictionaries accordingly. FYI, the dictionaries look like this:

```
person_to_friends = {'Jay Pritchett': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria 
Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado']...

person_to_networks = {'Claire Dunphy': ['Parent Teacher Association'], 
'Manny Delgado': ['Chess Club']...
```

I have this code so far where I am trying to read the file but I am having trouble because instead of making the first name a key, it makes every name till the newline a key.

```
friends = []
line = profiles_file.readline()
while line != '':
    profiles = format_name(line)
    if not profiles in person_to_friends:
        person_to_friends[profiles] = []
    line = profiles_file.readline()
    if not ',' in line:
        network = line
        line = profiles_file.readline()
    else:
        if format_name(line) != '' and format_name(line) not in person_to_friends[profiles]:
            person_to_friends[profiles].append(format_name(line))
            line = profiles_file.readline()


return person_to_friends
```

For reference format_name is just a function I have written to ensure the names in the file are in the form 'Firstname Lastname' and the newline characters are removed.

Comment: This is not a minimal example, is it?

Comment: I thnk the Minnesota phone directory would fit in perfectly here...

Comment: You don't use your dictionary anywhere in your last piece of code

Comment: I've updated my code